# Filenames with wildcards in variables

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
outbound=/home/user/outbound/
putfile=DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV
cd $outbound
filecnt=0
for file in $putfile; do let filecnt=filecnt+1; done
echo "Filecount: " $filecnt
```

So this code works well when there are files located in the outbound directory.  I can place files into the outbound path and as long as they match the putfile mask then the files are incremented as expected.

Where the problem comes in is if I run this while there are no files located in `$outbound`.
If there are zero files there `$filecnt` still returns a `1` but I'm looking to have it return a `0` if there are no files there.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `set -x` just below the `#!` line to watch what your script is doing.

If there is no matching file, then the wildcard is left unexpanded, and the loop runs once, with `file` having the value `DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV`.

To change that, set the nullglob option. Note that this only works in bash, not in sh.

```
shopt -s nullglob
putfile=DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV
for file in $putfile; do let filecnt=filecnt+1; done
```

Note that the `putfile` variable contains the wildcard pattern, not the list of file names. It might make more sense to put the list of matches in a variable instead. This needs to be an array variable, and you need to change the current directory first. The number of matching files is then the length of the array.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
outbound=/home/user/outbound/
cd "$outbound"
putfiles=(DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV)
echo "Filecount: " ${#putfiles}
```

If you need to iterate over the files, take care to protect the expansion of the array with double quotes, otherwise if a file name contains whitespace then it will be split over several words (and if a filename contains wildcard characters, they will be expanded).

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
outbound=/home/user/outbound/
cd "$outbound"
putfiles=(DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV)
for file in "${putfiles[@]}"; do
  echo "Processing $file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could test if file exists first

```
for file in $putfile; do
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    let filecnt=filecnt+1
  fi
done
```

Or look for your files with find

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name="$putfile"); do
  let filecnt=filecnt+1
done
```

or simply (fixed)

```
filecnt=$(find . -type f -name "$putfile" | wc -l); echo $filecnt
```

Comment: Beware that parsing the output of `find` in this way doesn't work if file names may contain whitespace or any of `\[?*` since the output is treated as a list of wildcard patterns. The last command won't work at all since it tries to execute `let` as an external command.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need a piece of code here. Following one liner should do your job.

```
ls ${outbound}/${putfile} | wc -l
```

Or

```
find ${outbound} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${putfile}" | wc -l
```

Comment: Beware that this doesn't work if there is a file name containing a newline character (which doesn't normally happen, but could be a robustness or security issue).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your feedback. Agree with you that `ls` may lead to such problem. Then I would prefer `find` followed by `wc`. I believe `find` is  robust enough. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It's the same problem: `find` is robust, but then `wc -l` would still count lines and not file names. You could use `find … -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c`, but it's easier to do the counting inside bash. Also counting from `find` will traverse subdirectories if there are any, which wasn't in the original requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, will take care next time.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when no matches are found, bash by default expands the wildcard `DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV` to the word `DATA_FILE_PUT_*.CSV` and therefore you end up with a count of 1.
To disable this behavior, use [shopt -s nullglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)