# redirect file names into a variable

Tags: shell, awk

Assume there are several files like the following

```
CLIENT_1.csv
CLIENT_2.csv
CLIENT_3.csv
CLIENT_4.csv
```

Is there any shell command/awk that we can use to direct the 1,2,3,4 into a variable named "ID"? So that we can do the following

```
if [ ${ID} != 4 ]
then
blah blah blah
fi
```

Comment: So you want to iterate through a list of files and those files are all located in the same directory? And is this a Unix os with bash?

Comment: Yes, i would like to iterate through a list of these files, and all the files are in the same directory, and it is Unix os with bash.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number part for each file:

```
for file in CLIENT_*.csv ; do
    id=${file%.csv}         # remove trailing '.csv'
    id=${id#CLIENT_}        # remove leading 'CLIENT_'
    if [ "$id" != 4 ] ; then ... ; fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a repeat of this question. 
[How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash)

It uses filename wildcarding to iterate through the list. In your case you would use:

```
for filename in /mydirectory/CLIENT_*.csv; do
   #whatever you wanted to do
done
```

Here is another way to do it where the filename string pattern is a variable.
[bash: filenames with wildcards in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233225/bash-filenames-with-wildcards-in-variables)
The file names are stored in the variable **file** (looking at the accepted answer) after the wildcarding is expanded in the for loop initialization. Again using the power of wildcarding your example would look something like this:

```
putfile=CLIENT_*.csv
for file in $putfile; do #whatever you wanted to do
done
```

Comment: No, the file _names_ will not get stored in the var, the string `CLIENT_*.csv` will. It gets expanded to matching file names on the second line, when it's used without double-quotes.